# Javascript that loops and stores keys as variables and outputs additional fields from keys stored?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm new to JS and coding in general so I'm not sure how to effectively write a function for this. I want to write a function that takes an object as an argument and returns another object.

```
OrderFormContents = {
    servicesSelected: {
        hdrPhotos: "selected",
        panos: "selected",
        twilightPhotos: "selected"
    }
}
```

`hdrPhotos`, `panos`, and `twilightPhotos` are all SKUs / unique identifiers.

I want to return an object like like:

```
CompletedOrderFormContents = {
    servicesSelected: {
        hdrPhotos: {
            sku: "hdrPhotos",
            calculatedPrice: 100, // returned from an object stored as a Session variable called calculatedPrices
            title: "HDR Photography" //returned from looking up the sku from a Services collection.
        },
        panos: {
            sku: "panos",
            calculatedPrice: 125,
            title: "Panoramas"
        },
        twilightPhotos: {
            sku: "twilightPhotos",
            calculatedPrice: 200,
            title: "Twilight Photography"
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have been brute forcing it, explicitely defining all of the skus, and it is dumb:

```
var myFunction = function(OrderFormContents) {

    CompletedOrderFormContents = {
        servicesSelected: ""
    };

    CompletedOrderFormContents.servicesSelected.hdrPhotos = {
        sku: "hdrPhotos",
        calculatedPrice: Session.get("calculatedPrices").hdrPhotos,
        title: Services.find({"sku" : "hdrPhotos"}).fetch()[0].title
    };

    CompletedOrderFormContents.servicesSelected.panos = {
        sku: "panos",
        calculatedPrice: Session.get("calculatedPrices").panos,
        title: Services.find({"sku" : "panos"}).fetch()[0].title
    };

    CompletedOrderFormContents.servicesSelected.twilightPhotos = {
        sku: "twilightPhotos",
        calculatedPrice: Session.get("calculatedPrices").twilightPhotos,
        title: Services.find({"sku" : "twilightPhotos"}).fetch()[0].title
    };

};
```

How would I refactor this code so I'm at least not explicitly defining the SKU for each statement and explicitly defining each statement for each SKU? I've got UnderscoreJS installed.

**EDIT** Got it working.

```
completedOrderFormContents = {
  servicesSelected: {}
};

for (sku in OrderFormContents.servicesSelected) {
  if (OrderFormContents.servicesSelected.hasOwnProperty(sku)) {
    completedOrderFormContents.servicesSelected[sku] = {
      sku: sku,
      price: Session.get("calculatedPrices")[sku],
      title: Services.find( { "sku" : sku }).fetch()[0].title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to learn about the basic [`for in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Don't use Underscore until you know this.

Comment: @Bergi, I added my attempt using `for... in` but there's one piece not working.

Comment: My tip is to refactor using arrays instead of objects. IMHO those are (in most cases) a lot easier to handle and come with order (object keys have no defined order) which can be quite handy sometimes. I'd have this instead `{ servicesSelected : ['hdrPhotos','panos', 'twilightPhotos'] }`. My rule is, if something is a list/enumeration/collection of things, always use an array. An object is for something describing a single thing (as in something that is IN a list). And when you have an array that is where the power of underscore comes in and you can very easily pick things out of it.

Comment: Mmmm... an array would not be good for `servicesSelected` because there is no order in a shopping cart and the services in the cart aren't enumerated anyway. For example, in one case `servicesSelected` would be `{ servicesSelected: {'hdrPhotos','panos','twilightPhotos'} }` whereas in another case it would be `{ servicesSelected: {'twilightPhotos','panos'} }`

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

```
//servicesSelected does not currently exist in completedOrderFormContents, 
//so gotta create it - ie. simply doing completedOrderFormContents = {} would not work 
//because the for loop is going to try and assign something to .servicesSelected
//later on and it needs that .servicesSelected key to already be there 

completedOrderFormContents = {
  servicesSelected: {}
};

for (sku in OrderFormContents.servicesSelected) {
  if (OrderFormContents.servicesSelected.hasOwnProperty(sku)) {
    completedOrderFormContents.servicesSelected[sku] = {
      sku: sku,
      price: Session.get("calculatedPrices")[sku],
      title: Services.find( { "sku" : sku }).fetch()[0].title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good! Though the `if`-statement with the `.hasOwnProperty()` test is usually not needed.

Comment: @Bergi Really? Isn't it necessary to ensure no extra hashes get added from the object's prototype or something?

Comment: Since your `OrderFormContents.servicesSelected` is a plain object (without a custom prototype), it won't inherit any enumerable properties.